# How to enter bash of an ubuntu docker container?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I want to run an `ubuntu` container and enter `bash`:

```
[root@localhost backup]# docker run ubuntu bash
[root@localhost backup]#
```

The `ubuntu` container exits directly. How can I enter the `bash`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-i` and `-t` options.

**Example:**

```
$ docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
root@9055316d5ae4:/# echo "Hello Ubuntu"
Hello Ubuntu
root@9055316d5ae4:/# exit
```

See: [Docker `run` Reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/)

> $ docker run --help | egrep "(-i,|-t,)"
>
> -i, --interactive=false    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>
> -t, --tty=false            Allocate a pseudo-TTY

**Update:** The reason this works and keeps the container running (*running `/bin/bash`*) is because the `-i` and `-t` options (*specifically `-i`*) keep `STDIN` open and so `/bin/bash` does not immediately terminate thus terminate the container. -- The reason you also need/want `-t` is because you presumably want to have an interactive terminal-like session so `t` creates a new pseudo-tty for you. -- Furthermore if you looked at the output of `docker ps -a` without using the `-i`/`-t` options you'd see that your container terminated normally with an *exit code* of `0`.

Comment: If no '-i -t', why does `ubuntu` container exit? Could you give a detailed explanation between adding `-i -t` options and no options?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! But I still have a little confusion: `-i, --interactive=false Keep STDIN open even if not attached`, what is the meaning of `attached`? Could you give an explanation?

Comment: "attached" means attached to a tty or pipe. This is the case if you just use ``-i`` by itself.

Comment: @JamesMills `Keep STDIN open even if not attached`, so, how can I attach to container in `docker run`? It seems that I must user `-i` if I want to use STDIN...